# NodeJS - create simple forwarding server

Tags: node.js, client

I'm trying to create a simple nodejs server to server program.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
-----------¦remote¦-----satellite link-----¦core¦---------
port 6999                port 7000                 port 6999
```

I need to write node.js code for both 'remote' and 'core'.

Here's what I have sofar (I'm a very confused now...):

```
//remote.js
var util=require('util');
var net=require('net');

var input=net.createServer(function(inputStream){
        inputStream.on('data', function(data) {
                util.puts(data);
        });
        var output=net.createServer(function(outputStream) {
                outputStream.pipe(inputStream, {end: false});

                outputStream.on('data',function(dta){
                        util.puts(dta);
                });
        });
        output.listen(7000, '172.16.1.224');
});
input.listen(6999, '172.16.1.224');
```

Once I have these two forwarding modules (remote and core) up-and-running, I'm hoping to do some packet inspection...

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call createConnection for output stream. Look at my port forwarding code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490898/node-js-forward-all-traffic-from-port-a-to-port-b/6500517#6500517)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define input and output as two connections, like so.

```
net.createServer(function(from) {
    var to = net.createConnection({
        host: addr.to[2],
        port: addr.to[3]
    });
    from.pipe(to);
    to.pipe(from);
}).listen(addr.from[3], addr.from[2]);
```

See [Node.js - forward all traffic from port A to port B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490898/node-js-forward-all-traffic-from-port-a-to-port-b/19637388#19637388)