# how to achive port forwarding in node.js using proxy server

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, express

I am working on the node js project and in which I have to forward request from one port to another port using proxy server, code available on net is not working or might be I am going wrong some where so please help me. with the working code which i can customize as per my requirement.

I have used code from [Node.js - forward all traffic from port A to port B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490898/node-js-forward-all-traffic-from-port-a-to-port-b)

also tried for the code :

```
 var util=require('util');
 var net=require('net');
 var input=net.createServer(function(inputStream){

 inputStream.on('data', function(data) {
            util.puts(data);
    });
    var output=net.createServer(function(outputStream) {
            outputStream.pipe(inputStream, {end: false});

            outputStream.on('data',function(dta){
                    util.puts(dta);
            });
    });output.listen(7000, 'localhost');

  });input.listen(6999, 'localhost');
```

This code which i have used in my application actually i have take requst from one port identify request according to param and forward to another port.

Comment: Add more info to the question. Do you have any code. Whats the message of the error? Its hard to even begin to help with this information.

Comment: Having two listeners seems... weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in the function handle request,  function(req, res):

```
var request = require('request');
//forward the request
request({
uri : 'http://localhost:anotherPort'+req.url,
method : req.method
}).pipe(res);
```