# Request multiply module for nodejs

Tags: node.js

Is there a node module where i can redirect live traffic to a alternative server(dev server) while serving them from production one?

requests<--->prod server---->dev server

Purpose of this to evaluate app performance on live traffic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490898/node-js-forward-all-traffic-from-port-a-to-port-b

Comment: Actually, i came across with a module long time ago. But i dont remember the name. Thats the issue.