# Using Node.js, can we map one domain / port (one origin) to two local web servers?

Tags: node.js

Our project already has Node.js installed, and we run 2 web servers accessible using:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000
>   http://127.0.0.1:9000

However, the second website needs to do AJAX to the first server, and the cross-origin policy would prevent this.  Using Node.js (possibly by `http-server`), can we map:

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/data to http://127.0.0.1:8000

and map everything else on

> http://127.0.0.1:8080 to http://127.0.0.1:9000

using just a few lines?

Comment: You are ideally looking for a proxy. You could use a reverse proxy like nginx or HAProxy, or, if you want a pure node.js solution, use http-proxy-middleware and start a server on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do it with [`node http proxy`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) as below.

```
var proxyPort = 8080;
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var options = {
    router: {
        'localhost': '127.0.0.1:9000',
    }
};

var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options);
proxyServer.listen(proxyPort);
```

Or following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19637388/3011380) to create one proxy native.

> ```
>  var net = require('net');
> // parse "80" and "localhost:80" or even "42mEANINg-life.com:80"
> var addrRegex = /^(([a-zA-Z\-\.0-9]+):)?(\d+)$/; 
> var addr = {
>     from: addrRegex.exec(process.argv[2]),
>     to: addrRegex.exec(process.argv[3])
> };    
> if (!addr.from || !addr.to) {
>     console.log('Usage: <from> <to>');
>     return;
> }    
> net.createServer(function(from) {
>     var to = net.createConnection({
>         host: addr.to[2],
>         port: addr.to[3]
>     });
>     from.pipe(to);
>     to.pipe(from);
> }).listen(addr.from[3], addr.from[2]);
> ```